# Android - Can't get value from EditText inside Custom Dialog

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog, android-edittext

I have been unsuccessful in getting the input from my EditText object inside my custom dialog.

```
 public class SetCityDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.city_dialog, null);


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_dialog, null))
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                //This is the input I can't get text from
                                EditText inputTemp = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_input_text);
                                //query is of the String type
                                query = inputTemp.getText().toString();
                                newQuery();
                                getJSON newData = new getJSON();
                                newData.execute("Test");
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                SetCityDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                            }
                        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

I don't get any exceptions, but the variable query is set to an empty string.
Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: have u tried it as `EditText inputTemp = (EditText) builder.findViewById(R.id.search_input_text);`

Comment: Yes, and Eclipse says to cast builder to an Activity type which unfortunately doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: then change  `builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_dialog, null))` to  `builder.setView(view)`

Comment: important point is use same View for accessing UI elements which you are setting for AlertDialog

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275051/cant-get-string-from-edittext-in-custom-alertdialog

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing and i get the same error. I don't no why. I already use AlertDialog.Builder in the past and get no trouble. But in your case change this code:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {

                            //This is the input I can't get text from
                            EditText inputTemp = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_input_text);
                            //query is of the String type
                            query = inputTemp.getText().toString();
                            newQuery();
                            getJSON newData = new getJSON();
                            newData.execute("Test");
                        }
```

By this one:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            Dialog f = (Dialog) dialog;
                            //This is the input I can't get text from
                            EditText inputTemp = (EditText) f.findViewById(R.id.search_input_text);
                            query = inputTemp.getText().toString();
                           ...
                        }
```

This solution works for me and it seems to be the same for you.
Found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799751/android-how-do-i-retrieve-edittext-gettext-in-custom-alertdialog)

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead :

```
View myLayout = nflater.inflate(R.layout.city_dialog, null);
EditText myEditText = (EditText) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
String valueOfEditText = myEditText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do that much coding. just change

```
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_dialog, null))
```

to

```
    builder.setView(view)
```

and access text of EditText using   **view.findView.....

```
    EditText inputTemp = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_input_text);
    String xyz = inputTemp.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is worked for me: 

// if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    Dialog inDialog = (Dialog) dialog;                    

                    EditText emailAddress = (EditText) inDialog.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
                    email = emailAddress.getText().toString();

                    if(email.length() == 0) {

                        objPublicDelegate.showToast("Please fill Email Address.");

                    }else{

                        objLoadingDialog.show("Please wait...");

                        // Call a network thread Async task 
                        mNetworkMaster.runForgetAsync(email);

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
```